# Running methods from Springs Crud repository asynchronously

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-async

I'm making an asynchronous repository using spring. I'm extending JpaRepository, which in turn extends CrudRepository. On my own methods I'm using the Async annotation so that they return CompletableFuture. Can I make the save function in CrudRepository return a CompletableFuture?

Comment: Did you try it?

Comment: Try what? I tried assuming that it would return a CompletableFuture to see if Spring sprinkled its' magic but that didn't work.

Comment: http://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-async

Comment: Yes, but i can't put an annotation on a method which lies in the internals of Spring. It's not my own method. It is a member of CrudRepository. If I try to Override the function with an async tag and specifiyng that it should return a CompletableFuture it says that the return type doesn't match the parent specification.

Comment: Did you manage to solve this?

Comment: @DavidKrenkel Unfortunately not. I made a wrapper class instead...